# Exception ALPN is not configured properly

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, grpc, apache-beam, alpn

I'm trying to create some cloud metrics from scala using scio and apache beam for a dataflow task.
I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ALPN is not configured properly. See https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/SECURITY.md#troubleshooting for more information.
```

I followed the steps at that URL and added a JVM param:
`-Djavaagent=/Users/user/Downloads/jetty-alpn-agent-2.0.6.jar`

I also have as env var: `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/etc/recsys/recsys-dev.json`

The code:

```
val pathToCredsFile = "/etc/recsys/recsys-dev.json"
val credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(pathToCredsFile)).createScoped(Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"))
val settings = MetricServiceSettings.newBuilder()
  .setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials))
  .build()
val metricServiceClient = MetricServiceClient.create(settings) <-throws ex whether or  not I use settings
```

Can I get some help?

Comment: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/SECURITY.md#troubleshooting

Comment: ya that's how I figured out I should use Djavaagent, but no success.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the [Google Cloud Java Troubleshooting](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md) document, specifically the [compatibility checker](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-util/google-cloud-compat-checker). Providing its output would be helpful for debugging.

jetty-alpn-agent-2.0.6 does not support JRE versions 1.8.0u161 and later. Upgrading to 2.0.7 or 2.0.9 may work better. But using jetty-alpn is discouraged. If you are using a supported platform, tcnative or Conscrypt are better alternatives.

There should also be some INFO logs with some additional details of what was wrong with Jetty ALPN/tcnative/Conscrypt (look for "netty-tcnative unavailable (this may be normal)"; there will be one log statement for each ALPN provider, with backtraces).

Answer (score 0):

You can add usePaneText() method before build() to solve the ALPN not configured issue as follows:

```
val settings = MetricServiceSettings.newBuilder()
  .setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials))
  .userPlainText()
  .build()
```

This will disable SSL for testing or dev env.

Note: not recommended for prod env.